# How to run tests in order they are written?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, ruby-1.9.3, testunit

I am trying to write test for testing sphinx search. I need user to pass some params to api, and based on that params shpinx to perform search.

I have following 3 test

in test_helper.rb I have everything set up

```
  require 'factory_girl'
  require 'thinking_sphinx/test'
  ThinkingSphinx::Test.init
  .........
  class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false
  fixtures :all
```

And my tests

```
test "should 1st test" do
  ThinkingSphinx::Test.start
  # uthenticatoin and creating records in databese with Factory Girl
  ThinkingSphinx::Test.index

  get "some/path", {params}, @headers

  assert_response :success
end

test "should 2nd test" do
  # uthenticatoin and creating records in databese with Factory Girl
  ThinkingSphinx::Test.index

  get "some/path", {params}, @headers

  assert_response :success
  # other assertions
end

test "should 3rd test" do
  # uthenticatoin and creating records in databese with Factory Girl
  ThinkingSphinx::Test.index

  get "some/path", {params}, @headers

  assert_response :success
  # other assertions
  ThinkingSphinx::Test.stop
end
```

I dont know why my tests run not in order they are written, but 2nd, 3rd, 1st
How can I make tests run in order thay are written. I am using basic Rails Test::Unit.
Order matters for me, because of test specifics.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests should never be written in such a way that order matters. I see why you want the order though, and there are ways to deal with that. Try this:

```
setup do
  ThinkingSphinx::Test.start
end

# Your tests

teardown do
  ThinkingSphinx::Test.stop
end
```

This makes it so that before *each* test `ThinkingSphinx::Test` is started, and stopped after *each* test. This is the ideal way to set this up, so now it doesn't matter what order your tests are run in.

However, if `ThinkingSphinx::Test.start` is a long process, you may not want it running for each test. I don't know if `TestUnit` gives you the ability to run a setup before an entire suite or set of tests, but in RSpec you're able to do that, and that would serve you better.